# Does toughness help to mitigate damage while in a "Downed State"?

Tags: guild-wars-2

Once you are put into the "Downed State", will damage reduction from toughness still apply?

Comment: Thanks for the editing and sorry about my bad english :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since toughness is added to armour at a rate of 100% (that is, 1 toughness = 1 armour) - this question is actually "does armour work while in a downed state".

The answer to this is yes - armour will mitigate its usual percentage of incoming damage while you're in a downed state.

It is worth noting that armour does not mitigate *condition damage*, only direct damage, so if you're poisoned or bleeding it won't help you much but if you have a Risen hitting on you it will.